# Understanding the correct workflow with Maven in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

For the first time, I'm using Maven when developing my Java project with Intellij IDEA. Mainly for its dependency-handling features.

Now, I'm trying to understand what would be the 'correct' general workflow. To run the tests, I think I should use the `test` phase button in the Maven projects view (is there a more graphic option)?

However what about running the project? Should I install the Maven `exec` plugin and use it inside Intellij? Or should I simply run with `ALT + SHIFT + F10` like I did until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical standalone Java program environment you can invoke the various Maven phases as you describe. They essentially do the equivalent of running `mvn <phase or plugin:goal>` from the command line. I find it more *empowering* to make sure that my builds and runs work from command line. As a result, I am not afraid to spend time to make sure the command line build works.

While unit testing, yes, you should use `Alt+Shift+F9` in a test class (after you have created a new test class for a functionality) to debug it or `Alt+Shift+F10` to run it. IDEA does everything you need to be able to

1. Run the whole class
2. Run a single test method

from within the IDE. On `Alt+Shift+F9`, it internally runs a JUnitStarter class that is equivalent of Maven's surefire plugin (but not the same). Here's what the console shows:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/8/Contents/Home/bin/java 
..../repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"
 com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 
org.kedar.java.reallyimp.ch1.Ch1Test
```

If you are using it to develop a web application, then you typically choose a deployment target (e.g. GlassFish or Tomcat) where the application is deployed. Of course, you will need to use a plethora of plugins to do this, but hopefully you will have all the proper `archetypes` to choose from so you are on your way.

Once you set up a deployment target using the handy "Edit Configurations" menu, you can just "run or debug" that configuration. This way, you can debug while your classes (e.g. servlets) execute in an actual runtime. IDEA has some support for dynamically loading classes upon modification (very useful in practice). For more complicated setups (or for JSP pages), you should consider using JRebel from ZeroTurnaround (a paid-for product) although this is your decision to make.

In short, make everything work from within the IDE. It's quite possible and IDEA does help us remain productive. Before you push your work to a repository however, make sure that your command line build e.g. `mvn test`, `mvn verify` etc. works.

### Workflow in Action (Answers to Comments by OP)

1. Consider that I want to use the apache-commons class `FileUtils`. I create a class `FileUtilsClient.java` and just type `FileUtils`. IDEA, rather smartly, asks me what to do with it. I ask it to add it as a Maven dependency. See [here](http://imgur.com/SfODjxU).
2. I add the code in a method named `areSame(File f1, File f2)` that uses say `FileUtils.contentEquals(File, File)`. At this point, go ahead and take a peek at your pom.xml. IDEA would have added the appropriate dependency code as this popular dependency is in a central repo available on the Internet.
3. Then I want to create a unit test for the method I just wrote. I go to my class declaration and do `Cmd+Shift+T`. IDEA offers me to create a new test since this is a brand new class. If the class already has a test class, it would offer me to take there.
4. I create the [JUnit 4 Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVAoV.jpg).
5. I code up the test method `@Test public void testSameness()` that tests **areSame** method in my class.
6. I then go to the method declaration `testSameness()` and do `Alt+Shift+F9` and IDEA, again, forms the correct classpath and runs my test. Sweet. Here's the command it runs (and [proof that it is doing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdXgX.jpg) as expected, by including the path to `commons-io.jar`).

Comment: So let me see: running the test suite in Intellij (using either `ALT+SHIFT+F10` or  `SHIFT+F10`) is *not* equivalent to running the `test` phase in Maven. For example, it doesn't fetch the dependencies specified in the `pom.xml`. However, you do recommend generally working like this, i.e. through standard Intellij features, and mostly using the Maven phases to make sure everything's alright before uploading to the repo (either through the command line or through the equivalent IDE buttons). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: And if my understanding is correct: when running the app (or tests), how does Intellij know to put the dependencies specified in `pom.xml` on the classpath? Are the standard `ALT+SHIFT+F10` and `SHIFT+F10` aware of Maven?

Comment: @AvivCohn, I added an addendum to my answer. Please see if that suffices.

Comment: Does the screenshot you posted in point 6 start with `java -cp`? So that means Intellij knows how to build the classpath for a Java project when you run it? And if you use Maven, it knows to include the dependencies from the Maven repo in the classpath?

Comment: Yes, [here](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/d18753e7bfd093c1b371). It's not clear exactly what you are doubting.

Comment: I wasn't sure Intellij knows by itself to include the dependencies from the Maven repo in the classpath. Thanks you :)